# Retrieving the data* value from my HTML and printing it into the console using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know what I've done wrong with this code, I've looked online and all I've seen to do is put the `window.onload = function()` at the start of the code. However, the value is always printed as null and I can't my head around why it's doing it.

Here is the code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    // Get the select element by its id
    const select = document.getElementById("select-filter");

    // Get the selected option element
    const selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

    // Get the data-select value
    const dataSelect = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-sel");

    // Print the data-select value to the console
    console.log(dataSelect);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-select-container">
  <!-- filter selector -->
  <div class="filter-selection-container">
    <select name="select-filter" id="select-filter">
      <option value="filter-all">All</option>
      <option value="filter-commercials" data-sel="1">Commercials</option>
      <option value="filter-fiction" data-sel="2">Fiction</option>
      <option value="filter-music-videos" data-sel="3">Music Videos</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: it's null because you run it onload and your selected option has defaulted to the first option (because you haven't marked any as selected) and that option doesn't have the `data-sel` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean for the `select` to have a [`change` listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on it, and then check the data attribute is defined before trying to log it.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select-filter");

select.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange() {
  const selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  const dataSelect = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-sel");
  if (dataSelect) console.log(dataSelect);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-select-container">
  <!-- filter selector -->
  <div class="filter-selection-container">
    <select name="select-filter" id="select-filter">
      <option value="filter-all">All</option>
      <option value="filter-commercials" data-sel="1">Commercials</option>
      <option value="filter-fiction" data-sel="2">Fiction</option>
      <option value="filter-music-videos" data-sel="3">Music Videos</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```